# Out_Folder_Path as a Parameter and OS.Path.Join

Tags: arcpy, csv

First, I am new to StackExchange and to Python.

I would like to allow my user to select the location to store results of a TableToTable conversion.

I do not understand how to convert the out_folder_path and out_name to parameters. My understanding is that the out_name is part of the out_folder_path. If that is the case, how can out_folder_path exist before out_name is created?

Can I set the out_folder_path equal to the workspace? (I have successfully set the workspace as a parameter)

I have read several posts regarding using os.path.join.

Below is my attempt to add t he code following the directions in advanced help.

```
#import arcpy
import arcpy

#import OS
import os

#setup environment
from arcpy import env

#set overwrite to true
env.overwriteOutput = True

#Set workspace as parameter
arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText (0) # -Type = workspace - let's user select database of shapefiles to convert to tables/spreadsheets


#Variables for creating folder
##Syntax: CreateFolder_management (out_folder_path, out_name)
out_folder_path = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) # Type = workspace; allows user to select location to save results
out_name = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2) #Type = string; allows user to name the folder for storing results


#Create A Folder to Store Spreadsheets
arcpy.CreateFolder_management(out_folder_path, out_name)


#Get a list of shapefiles in the folder
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
fcs_count = len(fcs)


for fc in fcs:
  outfc = os.path.join(out_folder_path, fc)
  ##Syntax: TableToExcel_conversion (Input_Table, Output_Excel_File, {Use_field_alias_as_column_header}, {Use_domain_and_subtype_description})
  arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion(fc,outfc)
```

Comment: Suggest you upload your code if you want a response.

Comment: What data types are you using on those two parameters in the properties of your tool dialog?

Answer (score 3):

I have a solution for you.

The problem is that your path joining isn't correct.

Let's say you have a folder workspace on D:\ called "StudyArea"
 with three different shape files in it. These are called:

- roads.shp
- powerlines.shp
- buildings.shp

Your `outfc = os.path.join(out_folder_path, fc)` would create the following:

- D:\OutputPath\roads.shp
- D:\OutputPath\powerlines.shp
- D:\OutputPath\buildings.shp

But `arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion(fc,outfc)` needs a .xls File as outFC. So you are giving a wrong output file definition to the TabletoExcel tool.

First of all you have to get rid of the .shp extension. This is done by:

```
tableName = os.path.basename(Input).rstrip(os.path.splitext(Input)[1])
```

`tableName` will receive the values:

- roads
- powerlines
- buildings

any of them without the extension.

Then you will have to add the .xls extension

Use:
outfc = os.path.join(out_folder_path, out_name, tableName + ".xls")

### Solution

So your code should look like this:

```
#import arcpy
import arcpy

#import OS
import os

#setup environment
from arcpy import env


#set overwrite to true
env.overwriteOutput = True

#Set workspace as parameter
arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText (0) # -Type = workspace - let's user select database of shapefiles to convert to tables/spreadsheets


#Variables for creating folder
##Syntax: CreateFolder_management (out_folder_path, out_name)
out_folder_path = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) # Type = workspace; allows user to select location to save results
out_name = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2) #Type = string; allows user to name the folder for storing results


#Create A Folder to Store Spreadsheets
arcpy.CreateFolder_management(out_folder_path, out_name)


#Get a list of shapefiles in the folder
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
fcs_count = len(fcs)


for fc in fcs:
  tableName = os.path.basename(fc).rstrip(os.path.splitext(fc)[1]) #get rid of any extension
  outfc = os.path.join(out_folder_path, out_name, tableName + ".xls")
  ##Syntax: TableToExcel_conversion (Input_Table, Output_Excel_File, {Use_field_alias_as_column_header}, {Use_domain_and_subtype_description})
  arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion(fc, outfc)
```

Comment: Thanks for the above comments. I will update and test my script per your ideas.  I read through several web pages on using import os.path.join.  I did not realize that the .shp needs to be stripped for this to work.

Comment: Thanks All. Alexander's code works and I was able to convert my out folder path and out name into parameters allowing users to select where to store the data!